# How to upload more than one ontology into protégé?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I am going to use protégé to critically evaluate linked data web resource, the resource has several devoted domain specific ontologies work underneath its data model. I need to know how I can upload these ontologies into the protégé and create several instance, in order to use SWRL and reasoning engine to evaluate the model?

Comment: you have to create one ontology that imports all others in order to be able to use reasoning on all ontologies at once. At least if you think there are some connections between those ontologies. If not, it doesn't matter - simply load them into separate windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it is really helpful, I just would like to mention that all the ontologies are used by the model to create geographic instances (individuals). thus they are related and there are direct connection between them. As I am new to the ontology concept and protégé ,  could you please elaborate a bit more on how to import all these ontologies together ?